# How to play a different audio file from right and left ear with headset on macOS?

Tags: audio

There are often song versions I want to compare and play at the same time.
I want to play one version from my left ear of my headphones, and the other song from the right ear of my headphones.

Is this possible?

I have an app called audio Hijack as well, if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/).  Load each audio file as a left and right stereo track.

You can then play the stereo output, with each file playing as a left and right stereo track through your headphones.  You can also save the file, as well to listen to later.

If the audio files are already stereo, you can use the `Split stereo into mono` [option](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/splitting_and_joining_stereo_tracks.html) to flatten them from stereo to mono.

Additionally, if the audio tracks arent synced, you can use Audacity to align the tracks.